# Has this symmetry between the sums with $\sin(r\pi n)$ in the denominator already discovered?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I know that the convergence sums in the form $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{3}\sin\left(rn\right)}$ is very closely related to irrationality measure, and thus it is very unlikely that there is any closed form for general sums like or similar to this. It is, however, possible that there is a symmetry relation in these sums for two numbers with the same irrationality measure, $r_1/r_2$ and $r_2/r_1$. Because of this, I was doing some research into finding this relation and proved the following equality:

$$\frac{1}{r_{1}^{2}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{n^{3}\sin\left(\frac{r_{1}}{r_{2}}\pi n\right)}+\frac{1}{r_{2}^{2}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{n^{3}\sin\left(\frac{r_{2}}{r_{1}}\pi n\right)}=-\frac{\pi^{3}}{720}\left(\frac{7r_{1}}{r_{2}^{3}}+\frac{10}{r_{1}r_{2}}+\frac{7r_{2}}{r_{1}^{3}}\right)$$

I find this equation stunning and beautiful, and because it is so elegant I thought that it would be impossible that it has not been discovered. I would really like it if someone could point me towards the proof of this identity if it has already been proven, or if someone knows a simple proof they could just write it out here. Thank you guys in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a proof of the identity. To make the situation a bit more clear, I'll work with the more general case of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^{2k+1}\sin(z\pi n)}$, where $k\geq1$ is an integer. A reciprocity formula of the same form as above still holds. Now let,

$$\tilde{f}_k(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^{2k+1}\sin(\pi nz)}.$$

Then whenever $\tilde{f}_k(z)$ converges, so does $\tilde{f}_k(-1/z)$, and

$$z^{-k}\tilde{f}_k\left(z\right)-z^{k}\tilde{f}_k\left(-z^{-1}\right)=\pi^{2k+1}\sum_{r=0}^{2k+2}a_{k,r}z^{k+1-r},$$

where $a_{k,r}\in \mathbb{Q}$ are rational coefficients. In fact, there is an explicit formula for the coefficients:

$$a_{k,r}=\frac{2^{2k+1}(-1)^{k+1}}{(2k+2)!}{2k+2 \choose r}B_r(1/2)B_{2k+2-r}(1/2)$$

where $B_k$ are the [Bernoulli polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials). I don't remember the proof off of the top of my head. I found it a while ago, and it is long, complicated, and unilluminating. The nicer argument is simply an existence claim: a reciprocity formula of this sort must hold, with some coefficients. I don't know how to prove these coefficients must be rational without the explicit formula, though. The big idea of the proof is simple:

> The reciprocity formula above is the "shadow" of a modular form.

To make this connection more clear we introduce a change of variables

$$f_k(z)=\tilde{f}_k(2z+1)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2k+1}\sin(2\pi nz)}.$$

The reciprocity formula is now expressed in the less symmetric form

$$f_k\left(\frac{-z-1}{2z+1}\right)=(2z+1)^{-2k}f_k(z)+\pi^{2k+1}\sum_{r=0}^{2k+2}a_{k,r}(2z+1)^{1-r}.$$

This means that $f_k(z)$ transforms like a weight $-2k$ modular form under the Mobius transformation attached to $\begin{pmatrix}-1 & -1 \\ 2 & 1\end{pmatrix}$, up to a rational function! In fact, we can say even more. The matrices $\begin{pmatrix}-1 & -1 \\ 2 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ generate the group

$$\Gamma_1(2)=\left\{\left.\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}\in\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})\right| c \equiv 0 \text{ mod }2\right\}.$$

Hence, the periodicity condition $f_k(z+1)=f_k(z)$ implies that $f_k(z)$ is a modular form on $\Gamma_1(2)$, up to rational functions. So, what's going on here? The summary is this:

> Taking the repeated derivative of $f_k(z)$ gives a modular form. By Bol's identity this shows that $f_k(z)$ has to be a modular form as well, up to rational functions.

To begin with this proof, we write out the Fourier series for $f_k(z)$:

\begin{align*}
f_k(z)&=-2i\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{2\pi n z i}}{n^{2k+1}(1-e^{4\pi n z i})}\\
&=-2i\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{2\pi n (2j+1) z i}}{n^{2k+1}}\\
&=-2i\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{d|n}\chi_2(n/d)d^{-{2k+1}}\right)e^{2\pi n z i}
\end{align*}

where $\chi_2$ is the unique Dirichlet character modulo $2$, $\chi_2(n)=\frac{1+(-1)^n}{2}$. Letting $D=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\frac{d}{d z}$, we find that

\begin{align*}
D^{2k+1}f_k(z)&=-2i\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{d|n}\chi_2(n/d)(n/d)^{{2k+1}}\right)e^{2\pi n z i}\\
&=-2i\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{d|n}\chi_2(d)d^{{2k+1}}\right)e^{2\pi n z i}.\\
\end{align*}

The [general theory of Eisenstein series](https://wstein.org/books/modform/modform/eisenstein.html#explicit-basis-for-the-eisenstein-subspace) this is a modular form of weight $2k$ over $\Gamma_1(2)$. We now conclude from [Bol's identity](https://math.vanderbilt.edu/rolenl/ModularFormsLecture14.pdf) that the $f_k(z)$, as the $(2k+1)$-fold integral of the modular form $D^{2k+1}f_k(z)$, must be a a modular form of weight $-2k$ over $\Gamma_1(2)$ up to rational functions, as desired.